# Why are PHP files in CMD launching Notepad++ instead of running in the prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad++, php, file-association

I'm trying to run a MediaWiki script called RunJobs.php, which I have done many times before on the same system. All of sudden, today when I try to run the script in CMD on Windows 10 ***instead of running, it launches Notepad++***.

I've tried to solve this by adjusting file associations, to no avail. I tried to remove file associations altogether through right-click, control panel, and through Notepad++ preferences. None of that worked.

I even tried associating .php files to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe`.

### My Question

How can I get my .php files to run in Windows command prompt again like they used to?

P.S.: I know how to troubleshoot and I can't identify anything that I changed that may have caused this problem.

### Resources

This post was close, but unfortunately, not a duplicate and didn't offer the answer to my challenge:

- [How do I stop Notepad++ taking back file associations?](https://superuser.com/questions/567785/how-do-i-stop-notepad-taking-back-file-associations)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\php.exe` has a *Debugger* string with the value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe` [like Notepad2 does](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/doc/notepad2-Replacement.html).

Comment: What course of action do you recommend?